# Midi input that doubles as gate voltage input

Tags: analog, opto-isolator, midi, synthesizer

I'm building something that would benefit from a midi-clock input, but also a analog clock input. In order to save space, i'd like to use a mini-jack with an adapter for the midi cable (as seen in the Arturia Beatstep pro for example) and have it double as a analog clock / gate input.

Seeing some synths have gate signals that go up to +15v, I'd need some protection in order not to fry the opto-coupler mandated by the midi input.
A simple resistor in front of the ir-led won't do the trick: the forward current will either be too low in midi-mode, or too high in +15v gate mode.

I guess the capacitance of a zener prevents me from using that as voltage protection, because it will be too slow for the midi signal. Maybe there is some other thing I overlooked?

Comment: How about a normal diode in series with a Zener?

Comment: My guess is a single ESD-protection diode has a low enough capacitance and high enough recovery speed to act as a voltage protection.

Comment: You can get special low capacitance TVS diodes.

Comment: Tip tangent: those MIDI DIN-to-3.5mm adapters don't appear to all be the same pinout....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are special low-capacitance TVS diodes, but they are designed for transients, not for continuous current.

HP's [Optoelectronics Application Manual](https://archive.org/details/HewlettPackard-OptoelectronicsApplicationsManualOCR) suggests to limit the current with a constant-current source in front of the optocoupler (section 3.6.1.2):

[image: optocoupler with constant-current source]

However, with MIDI, there is not enough voltage for this to work. (The 220 Ω resistor in the standard circuit drops about 1.1 V.)
So what you have to do instead is to shunt the surplus current:

[image: optocoupler with active voltage clamp]

This is the equivalent of a Zener; you still need another resistor to limit the overall current.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it should work. I'm not too good with analog stuff, but I can simulate this to find out what parts and values would work nicely.

Comment: actually, coming back to this, I first simulated and then built the current source solution and it works like a charm!